# mysql error Resource id #3?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the Resource id #3 error when I am trying to echo out the value of the column counter from the database. I want to get a single value only. Any ideas how can I do that ?

```
$Page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$num = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $Page);


$query = "SELECT * FROM hitscounter WHERE page='$num';";
$res = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {

mysql_query("UPDATE hitscounter SET counter=counter+1 Where page='$num'");
$views = mysql_query("SELECT counter FROM hitscounter WHERE page=555");
    mysql_fetch_array($views, MYSQL_NUM);
    mysql_free_result($views);
    echo $views;
}
```

Comment: Of course you are. You used `mysql_fetch_array` wrong. Therefore you're not echoing the **result** of the query since your `$views` is actually `mysql_query` call. Try to work out errors on your own, these are really trivial and answered thousands of times. php.net tells you the order of function arguments, check it out.

Comment: You are not storing the result of mysql_fetch_array()... it's not an error, $views is in fact a mysql resource because it's returned as a query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the `result` you get back from `mysql_fetch_array`, just like this:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($views, MYSQL_NUM);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: why do you the var $result and you are printing results ? (with S)

Comment: just as an example, print_r is a good debugging tool to check what the contents of your vars are.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition should be like this

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($res);
if (count($result) > 0){
echo 'do something';
}
```